# `:make` not echoing output to the command line

Tags: makeprg, compile-vim

I have a simple makefile as follow:

```
all: A.cpp
    g++ -o A.exe A.cpp 
    .\A
```

In A.cpp,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!\n" << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

In Neovim, if I run `:!make`, I get what I expect:

```
:!make
g++ -o A.exe A.cpp
.\A
Hello World!
```

But `:make` gives

```
:!make  >C:\Users\yeung\AppData\Local\Temp\nvimHfW5tI\3 2>&1

(1 of 5): <ff><fe>g
```

Although it also compiled A.cpp but the output is not seen. How to make `:make` to output "Hello World"?

Another question is what should I do so that Neovim can take input from stdin when I run `:make`?

My init.vim

```
call plug#begin(stdpath('data') . '/plugged')

Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plug 'Raimondi/delimitMate'
Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'
"Plug 'vim-scripts/c.vim'

call plug#end()

set number
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set termguicolors
set mouse=a
set foldmethod=syntax
set nofoldenable

let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion = 1
let g:delimitMate_expand_cr = 1 
let mapleader = "\<Space>"

"enable powershell in nvim
let &shell = has('win32') ? 'powershell' : 'pwsh'
set shellquote= shellxquote= 
set shellcmdflag=-NoLogo\ -NoProfile\ -ExecutionPolicy\ RemoteSigned\ -Command
set shellredir=\|\ Out-File\ -Encoding\ UTF8


inoremap <C-Z> <C-O>u

nnoremap <C-Z> u
nnoremap <Leader>o o<Esc>
nnoremap <Leader>O O<Esc>
nnoremap <C-J> i<CR><Esc>  
nnoremap <F9> :YcmCompleter FixIt<CR>
nnoremap <F10> :w<CR>:!make %<<CR>
nnoremap <leader>to :YcmCompleter GoToDeclaration<CR>
nnoremap <leader>n :NERDTreeFocus<CR>
nnoremap <C-t> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
nnoremap <C-f> :NERDTreeFind<CR>

autocmd FileType makefile set noexpandtab.
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! The `<ff><fe>` sequence is the [Unicode BOM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), commonly used on Windows, so this suggests a possible encoding issue... Do you set any of the encoding options explicitly in your vimrc? (Maybe try under `vim --clean` to see if you can still reproduce the issue.)

Comment: Couldn't it be an issue with `'shellquote'` default value? Ages ago I had to change them to the following: https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-system-tools/blob/master/plugin/system_utils.vim#L279 So far, it's still working, with gvim under Windows.

Comment: @filbranden I am using nvim and `nvim --clean` displays correctly. How do I get it work in normal nvim?

Comment: Can you share your init.vim (and maybe plug-ins you use)? If it works fine in `nvim --clean`, it means it's one of your settings that's breaking it...

Comment: Maybe it's `'shellpipe'` that's missing? Try `set shellpipe=\|\ Out-File\ -Encoding\ UTF8` to see if that helps...

Comment: Or just drop all that block setting it to use `powershell`... If with `--clean` it works, then dropping those four lines should get that fixed, I'd expect.

Comment: @filbranden setting 'shellpipe' works like a charm!

Comment: @LearningMathematics You mean this one, right? `set shellpipe=\|\ Out-File\ -Encoding\ UTF8`

Comment: yes adding it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because a `'shellpipe'` of the default of `>` (which is the default on Windows) doesn't really work on Powershell. It seems to have it produce a file that uses UTF-16 encoding and then NeoVim has trouble parsing the [Unicode BOM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character at the beginning of it.

The `'shellredir'` setting gives us a good clue of how to solve it... So just setting `'shellpipe'` to the same should fix it:

```
set shellpipe=\|\ Out-File\ -Encoding\ UTF8
```

It seems that the NeoVim recommendations for `'shellpipe'` when using Powershell are incorrect, so I opened [Issue #13713](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/13713) to report this documentation problem to the NeoVim project.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your code with `:make`, the result is put into the quickfix list, you can open it with `:cope`

See `help :make`
See `help quickfix`

You can also make your own command that show immediatelly your results:

```
command! -nargs=* Make :make <args> | cope
```

You just have to use `:Make` instead of `:make` to run your programm and be prompted to the quickfix list.

See `:help command`

Comment: This is not the problem. I still see the same thing "<ff><fe>g" in my quickfix list. But thanks for your help.